# Android Studio: Most efficient way of fetching huge text data and then displaying in Activity

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

What is the most efficient way of fetching data and displaying in activity.
I used to fetch text items using

```
<string-array name="data">
  <item>
     Hii how are you? 
     .
     . +
     1000 lines of words
  </item>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an XML string array resource, which contains huge strings.
How about keeping your huge text data in separate files within assets directory, and may be keeping filenames in your string array resource.
Then by filename you can open and load text data from the asset file.

Here I am proposing a way to efficiently load huge text data and display them in an Activity.

I am using a thread to read huge text files in background.

Thread uses a BufferedReader to read large stream of data from the file.
BufferedReader is buffering characters from the data stream so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.

In below example, thread uses BufferedReader to read text data line by line.
It reads text line by line and sends them to the Activity through a Handler.

This is a Kotlin class to represent a line of text. It holds the text string and the line number.

TextLine.kt

```kotlin
class TextLine(
    val lineNumber: Int,
    val textLine: String
)
```

This is the Thread class that reads text line by line.

TextReaderThread.kt

```kotlin
class TextReaderThread(private val mInputStream: InputStream,
                       private val mTextLineHandler: Handler) : Thread() {

    private val mStopped = AtomicBoolean(false)

    override fun run() {
        mStopped.set(false)

        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(mInputStream))

        // Read first line
        var lineNumber = 1
        var textLine: String? = bufferedReader.readLine()

        while (null != textLine) {
            // Send read line to MainActivity
            Message.obtain(mTextLineHandler, 0, TextLine(lineNumber, textLine)).sendToTarget()

            // Check if thread is interrupted and stopped
            if(mStopped.get()) break

            // Read next line
            textLine = bufferedReader.readLine()
            lineNumber++
        }
    }

    override fun interrupt() {
        super.interrupt()
        // Thread is interrupted to stop
        mStopped.set(true)
    }

}
```

To display data in a scrollable view, I use a RecyclerView in the Activity.

RecyclerView can efficiently handle and render a large number of data when user scrolls through the data.

This is the layout of single line of data that will be populated in RecyclerView.
Left TextView displays the line number and right TextView displays the text line.

list_item.xml

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lineNumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLine"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="9"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/lineNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the Adapter and ViewHolder classes for RecyclerView.

TextLineAdapter.kt

```kotlin
class TextLineAdapter(private val mContext: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    private val mItems = mutableListOf<TextLine>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = mItems.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.lineNumber.text = mItems[position].lineNumber.toString()
        holder.textLine.text = mItems[position].textLine
    }

    fun addTextLine(textLine: TextLine) {
        // Add new item to the end of list
        mItems.add(textLine)
        // Notify that an item is added to end of the list
        notifyItemInserted(mItems.size - 1)
    }

    fun clear() {
        // Clear item list
        mItems.clear()
        // Notify that full data set has been changed
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}

class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val lineNumber = view.lineNumber
    val textLine = view.textLine
}
```

This is layout of the Activity.

activity_main.xml

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the Activity class.

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mTextLineHandler: Handler

    private lateinit var mTextReaderThread: Thread

    private lateinit var mTextLineAdapter: TextLineAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Create Handler which uses main looper, to handle messages from TextReaderThread
        mTextLineHandler = object : Handler(mainLooper) {
            override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                // Add text line received from TextReaderThread to recycler view
                mTextLineAdapter.addTextLine(msg.obj as TextLine)
            }
        }

        // Set layout manager and adapter of recycler view
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(baseContext)
        mTextLineAdapter = TextLineAdapter(baseContext)
        recyclerView.adapter = mTextLineAdapter
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Clear recycler view
        mTextLineAdapter.clear()

        // Create TextReaderThread to read text lines from assets/alice29.txt file.
        // Text lines read by TextReaderThread will be received and handled by mTextLineHandler.
        mTextReaderThread = TextReaderThread(assets.open("alice29.txt"), mTextLineHandler)
        // Start TextReaderThread
        mTextReaderThread.start()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        // Interrupt TextReaderThread to stop
        mTextReaderThread.interrupt()
        // Wait until TextReaderThread stops
        mTextReaderThread.join()
    }

}
```

In this example I use just one large text file named alice29.txt.
I downloaded alice29.txt file from http://corpus.canterbury.ac.nz/descriptions/

This example app reads only one huge text file (alice29.txt) and load content in to the RecyclerView as shown in following screenshots.

Top of the RecyclerView.

[image]

Scrolled to the bottom of the RecyclerView.

[image]

RecyclerView contains 3609 of text lines.

Comment: THanks mate for your help..... Really appreciate it... I owe you :)

Comment: I'm glad that it helps. Please accept the answer if you think it is the best solution for what you asked for. Follow instructions in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).